# How to create dynamically hub section from data source?

Tags: c#, windows-8.1, windows-rt

I now working on a project using windows 8.1. I have researched and known that pivot control is now being replaced by Hub control. Imagine that I have a list Category like that:

```
<Category>
<Private>
<Public>
<...>
</Category>
```

And now I want to create hub sections in xaml page which depend on the number of list Category's children. Please help me to solve it, I have read many documents but I just realized that perhaps hub section can only create manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamic add Hub Section in C#.  As far as I know, it can not dynamic add hub section only use XAML.

```
HubSection hubSection= new HubSection();

this.Hub.Sections.Add(theHubSection);
```

read this:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7c9b4355-59de-4a5a-bf7d-3459a2ee760d/adding-hubsections-dynamically?forum=w81prevwCsharp